# Is there a global page/post/product/anything ID?

Tags: posts, wp-query, menus

I am working on compression plugin and need to save compressed styles in to a file. Compression process is done but I need a unique page ID for any WP page in order to save and name the compressed file.

something like

```
style-post4852.css
```

Does WP have a simple function or a way to return current anything page ID. 
So far it looks like I have to do multiple conditionals like `is_page(), is_product() is_whetever_it_is()`, in order to figure out where I am.

Than I tried

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
     if( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
            var_dump($item);
     }
     return $classes;
}
```

which works fine until you start browsing Woocommerce single product or bbPress forum posts and than you get nothing.

Is there any way to get unified page/post/product/any_page WP identifier ?

**update:**

can I use this as global ID ?

```
get_queried_object_id()
```

Comment: What do you mean in "where I am"?

Comment: I need global page identifier , no matter if I am on product page or blog category or post/portfolio/project/forumpost/page , need something ( function , hook , var ) that would give me the ID of the  page " where I am " identifier.

Comment: its url should serve as one?

Comment: @MarkKaplun thnx for helping out. I edited the question so that you would better understand the usage of the ID I need.

Comment: now it is easier to understand the question, but still the url is the best thing to use, hash it and you got your ID. IIRC this is what caching plugins do.

Comment: @MarkKaplun , post as answer so I can can accept it . Combined with this + hash we got a winner https://kovshenin.com/2012/current-url-in-wordpress/

Comment: What about the global $post variable - or global $wp_query and grab the queried object ID from that?